# Counting Array on json_decode using PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to count the values of the json_decode in the php script but I can't locate how to count them.

Here's the json that has been decoded

```
{"fruits":[{"Apple":[1,2,3,4,5,
```

My expected output should be 5

I tried this list of codes but I dont get it right.

```
print_r(count($var["fruits"][0][0]));
```

can you guide me to the right direction?

Comment: `{"fruits":[{"Apple":[1,2,3,4,5,` is not a valid json

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print

```
$json = '{
    "fruits": [{
        "Apple": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "Orange":[8,6,4,3]
    }]
}';

$array = json_decode($json,true);

foreach ($array['fruits'][0] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key." count is : ".sizeof($value)."<br>";
}
```

or you can add it to an array

```
$json = '{
    "fruits": [{
        "Apple": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "Orange":[8,6,4,3]
    }]
}';

$array = json_decode($json,true);
$count_array=array();
foreach ($array['fruits'][0] as $key => $value) {
    $count_array+=[$key => sizeof($value)];
}
print_r($count_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

pass json_decode() second argument as true using that it return to array of json properties after that you can get one by one and count  ref:[Link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$json = '{
    "fruits": [{
        "fruit1": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        "fruit2": [1, 2],
        "fruit3": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,7,8]
    }],
    "veg": [{
        "veg1": [1, 2, 3, 5],
        "veg2": [1, 2],
        "veg3": [1, 5,6,7,8]
    }]
}';
$json_array=json_decode($json,true);
$count=array();
foreach ($json_array as $key => $data) {
    $data_array=array();
    foreach ($data as $datakey => $object_array) {
        #this foreach use becouse fruits has array of object
        foreach ($object_array as $object_key => $object) {
            $data_array["$object_key"] =sizeof($object);
        }   
    }
    $count["$key"] =$data_array;
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($count);
echo "</pre>";
```

here is output

```
Array
(
    [fruits] => Array
        (
            [fruit1] => 5
            [fruit2] => 2
            [fruit3] => 8
        )

    [veg] => Array
        (
            [veg1] => 4
            [veg2] => 2
            [veg3] => 5
        )

)
```

after that you can use `echo $count["fruits"]["fruit1"]` for print count